# How to use tf.cond for batch processing

Tags: tensorflow, conditional-statements

I want to use [tf.cond(pred, fn1, fn2, name=None)](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#case) for conditional branching. Let say I have two tensors: `x, y`. Each tensor is a batch of 0/1 and I want to use this tensors compression `x < y` as the source for
**tf.cond** `pred` argument:

> pred: A scalar determining whether to return the result of fn1 or fn2.

But if I am working with batches then it looks like I need to iterate over the source tensor inside the graph and make slices for every item in batch and apply tf.cond for every item. Looks suspiciously as for me. Why tf.cond not accept batch and only scalar? Can you advise what is the right way to use it with batch?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) sounds like what you want: a vectorized selection between Tensors.

`tf.cond` is a control flow modifier: it determines which ops are *executed*, and so it's difficult to think of useful batch semantics.

We can also put together a mixture of these operations: an operation which slices based on a condition and passes those slices to two branches.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.util import nest

def slicing_where(condition, full_input, true_branch, false_branch):
  """Split `full_input` between `true_branch` and `false_branch` on `condition`.

  Args:
    condition: A boolean Tensor with shape [B_1, ..., B_N].
    full_input: A Tensor or nested tuple of Tensors of any dtype, each with
      shape [B_1, ..., B_N, ...], to be split between `true_branch` and
      `false_branch` based on `condition`.
    true_branch: A function taking a single argument, that argument having the
      same structure and number of batch dimensions as `full_input`. Receives
      slices of `full_input` corresponding to the True entries of
      `condition`. Returns a Tensor or nested tuple of Tensors, each with batch
      dimensions matching its inputs.
    false_branch: Like `true_branch`, but receives inputs corresponding to the
      false elements of `condition`. Returns a Tensor or nested tuple of Tensors
      (with the same structure as the return value of `true_branch`), but with
      batch dimensions matching its inputs.
  Returns:
    Interleaved outputs from `true_branch` and `false_branch`, each Tensor
    having shape [B_1, ..., B_N, ...].
  """
  full_input_flat = nest.flatten(full_input)
  true_indices = tf.where(condition)
  false_indices = tf.where(tf.logical_not(condition))
  true_branch_inputs = nest.pack_sequence_as(
      structure=full_input,
      flat_sequence=[tf.gather_nd(params=input_tensor, indices=true_indices)
                     for input_tensor in full_input_flat])
  false_branch_inputs = nest.pack_sequence_as(
      structure=full_input,
      flat_sequence=[tf.gather_nd(params=input_tensor, indices=false_indices)
                     for input_tensor in full_input_flat])
  true_outputs = true_branch(true_branch_inputs)
  false_outputs = false_branch(false_branch_inputs)
  nest.assert_same_structure(true_outputs, false_outputs)
  def scatter_outputs(true_output, false_output):
    batch_shape = tf.shape(condition)
    scattered_shape = tf.concat(
        [batch_shape, tf.shape(true_output)[tf.rank(batch_shape):]],
        0)
    true_scatter = tf.scatter_nd(
        indices=tf.cast(true_indices, tf.int32),
        updates=true_output,
        shape=scattered_shape)
    false_scatter = tf.scatter_nd(
        indices=tf.cast(false_indices, tf.int32),
        updates=false_output,
        shape=scattered_shape)
    return true_scatter + false_scatter
  result = nest.pack_sequence_as(
      structure=true_outputs,
      flat_sequence=[
          scatter_outputs(true_single_output, false_single_output)
          for true_single_output, false_single_output
          in zip(nest.flatten(true_outputs), nest.flatten(false_outputs))])
  return result
```

Some examples:

```
vector_test = slicing_where(
    condition=tf.equal(tf.range(10) % 2, 0),
    full_input=tf.range(10, dtype=tf.float32),
    true_branch=lambda x: 0.2 + x,
    false_branch=lambda x: 0.1 + x)

cross_range = (tf.range(10, dtype=tf.float32)[:, None]
               * tf.range(10, dtype=tf.float32)[None, :])
matrix_test = slicing_where(
    condition=tf.equal(tf.range(10) % 3, 0),
    full_input=cross_range,
    true_branch=lambda x: -x,
    false_branch=lambda x: x + 0.1)

with tf.Session():
  print(vector_test.eval())
  print(matrix_test.eval())
```

Prints:

```
[ 0.2         1.10000002  2.20000005  3.0999999   4.19999981  5.0999999
  6.19999981  7.0999999   8.19999981  9.10000038]
[[  0.           0.           0.           0.           0.           0.
    0.           0.           0.           0.        ]
 [  0.1          1.10000002   2.0999999    3.0999999    4.0999999
    5.0999999    6.0999999    7.0999999    8.10000038   9.10000038]
 [  0.1          2.0999999    4.0999999    6.0999999    8.10000038
   10.10000038  12.10000038  14.10000038  16.10000038  18.10000038]
 [  0.          -3.          -6.          -9.         -12.         -15.
  -18.         -21.         -24.         -27.        ]
 [  0.1          4.0999999    8.10000038  12.10000038  16.10000038
   20.10000038  24.10000038  28.10000038  32.09999847  36.09999847]
 [  0.1          5.0999999   10.10000038  15.10000038  20.10000038
   25.10000038  30.10000038  35.09999847  40.09999847  45.09999847]
 [  0.          -6.         -12.         -18.         -24.         -30.
  -36.         -42.         -48.         -54.        ]
 [  0.1          7.0999999   14.10000038  21.10000038  28.10000038
   35.09999847  42.09999847  49.09999847  56.09999847  63.09999847]
 [  0.1          8.10000038  16.10000038  24.10000038  32.09999847
   40.09999847  48.09999847  56.09999847  64.09999847  72.09999847]
 [  0.          -9.         -18.         -27.         -36.         -45.
  -54.         -63.         -72.         -81.        ]]
```

Comment: The goal is to "control flow". That's why I need tf.cond. But you are totally right that with current architecture it is "difficult to think of useful batch semantics". I can only use SGD. Thank you! Now I have realized this.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about the problem you're trying to solve? Happy to help brainstorm solutions.

Comment: Lets imagine three branches on control flow before the tf.cond(two brachnes - detectors(d1,d2), and one - data source(ds).
Also there are two branches after the tf.cond (p1, p2).

Let simplify details and say that if the output of the first detector is bigger or equal than the output of the second, then the data from the data source(ds) branch should be processed by the p1 branch in other case - by p2 branch.  
We shouldn't process both branches at the same time.

Comment: Are there side effects of the processing (e.g. variable assignment)? If not, tf.where should work as-is, granted with a bit of redundant computation. Depending on the specifics of the problem, you might be able to optimize slightly by slicing the input based on the condition (yielding two Tensors, one with a batch of inputs to the first pipeline, one with a batch of inputs to the second).

Comment: Yes, the problem is that p1 and p2 will assign the result of processing to the same variable in the end of both branches. That var will be used as a result of processing and for loss computing.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, the assignment happens downstream, so either `tf.where` with redundant computation or the maybe-more-efficient slicing (plus interleaving at the end) works, right? Happy to write an example of the second, just want to make sure it'll be helpful. Also not clear on the loss computation: are you saying the variable assignment happens before/as part of the loss computation (just seems somewhat unusual)?

Comment: If would be great to see the example. In the end of p1 or p2 we assign the result variable value, let say the class Prediction. And then we are using this prediction as usually for the loss computation. The main thing is to save computational resources by processing only one branch.

Comment: Alright, a bit more complicated than I thought, but I think it works.