# How can i input boolean tensors to tf.cond() not just one boolean?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, data-science

Here is what I want to implement f(x) with tensorflow

input x = (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)

define f(x) = f1(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) + f2(x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)

where

> f1(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) = {1                  if
>   (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)=(0,0,0,0,0),
>
> ```
>                    g1(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) otherwise}
> ```
>
> f2(x5,x6,x7,x8,x9) = {1                  if
>   (x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)=(0,0,0,0,0),
>
> ```
>                    g2(x5,x6,x7,x8,x9) otherwise}
> ```

### This is my tensorflow code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
ph = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, 9])
x1 = tf.slice(ph, [0, 0], [-1, 5])
x2 = tf.slice(ph, [0, 4], [-1, 5])
fixed1 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 5])
fixed2 = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1, 5])

# MLP 1
w1 = tf.Variable(tf.ones([5, 1]))
g1 = tf.matmul(x1, w1)

# MLP 2
w2 = tf.Variable(-tf.ones([5, 1]))
g2 = tf.matmul(x2, w2)

check1 = tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x1, fixed1), axis=1, keep_dims=True)

check2 = tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(x2, fixed2), axis=1, keep_dims=True)

#### with Problem
f1 = tf.cond(check1,
                   lambda: tf.constant([2], dtype=tf.float32), lambda: g1)
f2 = tf.cond(check2,
                   lambda: tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.float32), lambda: g2)
####
f = tf.add(f1, f2)

x = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

fixed = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('(1)\n', sess.run(check1, feed_dict={ph: x, fixed1: fixed, fixed2: fixed}))
    print('(2)\n', sess.run(check2, feed_dict={ph: x, fixed1: fixed, fixed2: fixed}))
    print('(3)\n', sess.run(f, feed_dict={ph: x, fixed1: fixed, fixed2: fixed}))
    print('(4)\n', sess.run(f1, feed_dict={ph: x, fixed1: fixed, fixed2: fixed}))
    print('(5)\n', sess.run(f2, feed_dict={ph: x, fixed1: fixed, fixed2: fixed}))
```

---

In this case,

check1 is [[ True], [ True], [False], [False], [False]] with shape (5, 1)

check2 is [[ True], [False], [ True], [ True], [ True]] with shape (5, 1)

I expect result of f is [[3], [1], [2], [3], [10]]

but seems like tf.cond() can not handle input as boolean tensors with shape (5, 1)

Could you advice how to implement f(x) with tensorflow, please.

This is Error message what i received

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 670, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>       status)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py",
>   line 66, in **exit**
>       next(self.gen)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py",
>   line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
>       pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status)) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape
>   must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with
>   input shapes: [?,1], [?,1].
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/hong/Dropbox/MLILAB/Research/GM-MLP/code/tensorflow_cond.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       lambda: tf.constant([2], dtype=tf.float32), lambda: g1)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 1765, in cond
>       p_2, p_1 = switch(pred, pred)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 318, in switch
>       return gen_control_flow_ops._switch(data, pred, name=name)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_control_flow_ops.py",
>   line 368, in _switch
>       result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Switch", data=data, pred=pred, name=name)   File
>   "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py",
>   line 759, in apply_op
>       op_def=op_def)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 2242, in create_op
>       set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1617, in set_shapes_for_outputs
>       shapes = shape_func(op)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py",
>   line 1568, in call_with_requiring
>       return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
>       debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)   File "C:\Users\hong\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\common_shapes.py",
>   line 675, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>       raise ValueError(err.message) ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 2 for 'cond/Switch' (op: 'Switch') with input shapes: [?,1],
>   [?,1].
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Would like to see this question directly addressed. Lot's of work-arounds are presented as answers, but tf.cond() should accept tensors if it is to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need tf.where, not tf.cond.

See the answer to this question: [How to use tf.cond for batch processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159946/how-to-use-tf-cond-for-batch-processing)