# Toggling between tensors in two separate batches

Tags: tensorflow

Let's say x and y are two `N-dimensional` tensors, where both have the same dimensions and the first dimension is of size S (the batch size). Let's say b is a `1-dimensional` tensor of booleans, of size S.

I want to produce z, a N-dimensional tensor defined as:

```
z[i] = b[i] ? x[i] : y[i] for i from 0 to (S-1)
```

where `x[i]` refers to the i-th `(N-1)-dimensional` slice of x.

What is the easiest way to do this? I thought tf.cond would work, but it only accepts scalar-valued predicates. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[tf.where](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) should work, and supports this kind of broadcasting. If you find yourself wanting a batch version of conditional execution (where one or both branches are expensive to compute), that's [also possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159946/how-to-use-tf-cond-for-batch-processing/42164494#42164494).

Comment: tf.where looks perfect, thanks!
Do you happen to know if there is a variant of this function that branches more than 2 ways?

Comment: You could `tf.stack` the Tensors you want to branch between and then `tf.gather` to select between them.